# Magento2 Getting error as variable @baseUrl is undefined in file /var/view_preprocessed

Tags: magento2, base-url, static-content-deploy

On doing php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

I am getting error

> Compilation from source:
>   vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/email-inline.less variable
>   @baseUrl is undefined in file
>   var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/source/_email-extend.less
>   in _email-extend.less on line 19, column 13 17| // as the latter will
>   cause font rendering issues if the web fonts are inaccessible. 18| 19|
>   @import url("@{baseUrl}css/email-fonts.css");

Final Error

> [Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException]   Cannot read
>   contents from file
>   "/pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/email-inlin   e.css"
>   Warning!file_get_contents(pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/email-inli
>   ne.css): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

I followed this process

1. Remove pub/static [Keep the .htaccess backed up and copy it again]
2. Remove var/cache
3. Remove var/composer_home
4. Remove var/generation
5. Remove var/page_cache
6. Remove var/view_preprocessed
7. run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

But getting the same error, Dont know whats is wrong

Comment: It is a permission issue. Assign the right folder permissions

Comment: I can also see this @baseUrl is undefined in file var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/source/_email-extend.less, Kindly let me know the files I have to provide permission. apart from  pub and var

Answer (score 1):

My `lib/web` folder was empty, I got them from by Backup.

When I searched for `locate _email-extend.less` I found the mission files.

I did penetration testing, I got some duplicate theme files in my `pub/static/theme`, On deleting them something wrong happened. Still dont know how this files generated.

Finally to recover I did the steps again.

```
rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/* var/session/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/*

sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade;
sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile;
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f;
sudo php bin/magento indexer:reindex;
sudo php bin/magento cache:clean;
sudo php bin/magento cache:flush;
sudo chmod -R 0777 pub/;
sudo chmod -R 0777 var/;
```

Don't forget to Keep the .htaccess backed-up and paste them again to `pub/static/`